# type mismatch; found : play.api.data.Form[controllers.Application.Userdata] required: play.api.data.Form[(String, String)]

Tags: scala, playframework, eclipse-kepler

i have created a simply login submit form using playframework and scala without connecting any database.

**my `application.scala` which is my controller i have written the code**

```
import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.data._
import play.api.data.Forms._
import play.api.mvc.Request
import views.html._

case class Userdata(email:String,password:String)

object Application extends Controller {

  case class Userdata(email:String,password:String)

  val userForm = Form(
  mapping(
    "email" -> text,
    "password" -> text
  )(Userdata.apply)(Userdata.unapply)
)

   def usercheck = Action{ implicit request=>

    userForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
      formWithErrors => BadRequest(views.html.login(formWithErrors)),
         Userdata => {  Ok(views.html.index("congrates"))}

    )}
    def index() = Action {
    implicit request=>
    Ok(views.html.login(userForm))
  }
```

and my view template is `login.scala.html`..

```
@(form: Form[(String,String)])

@import helper._


    @form(routes.Application.usercheck){
    <form class=frmuuser>
      <input type=text placeholder=email id='emailid'>
      <input type=password placeholder=password id='pwd'>
      <input type=submit value=login id='enter'>

    </form>
    }
```

but it is not working and giving me error

```
type mismatch; found : play.api.data.Form[controllers.Application.Userdata] required: play.api.data.Form[(String, String)]
```

in this line of contoller

```
 formWithErrors => BadRequest(views.html.login(formWithErrors)),
```

what is soultion for my problem??

Answer (score -1):

Few points to note:

- Put your case class `Userdata` outside the Application controller. That is move it inside controller package.
- Also  you can add @import at the beginning of your template, to import any arbitrary package or class.

Try this.

`Application.scala`:  only one `Userdata` case class definition ( you had two of these classes defined )

```
import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.data._
import play.api.data.Forms._
import play.api.mvc.Request
import views.html._

case class Userdata(email:String, password:String)

object Application extends Controller {

  val userForm = Form(
  mapping(
    "email" -> text,
    "password" -> text
  )(Userdata.apply)(Userdata.unapply)
)

   def usercheck = Action{ implicit request=>

    userForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
      formWithErrors => BadRequest(views.html.login(formWithErrors)),
         Userdata => {  Ok(views.html.index("congrates"))}

    )}
    def index() = Action {
    implicit request=>
    Ok(views.html.login(userForm))
  }
```

`login.scala.html`: use `Userdata` instead of `(String, String)`

```
@(form: Form[Userdata])
@import helper._

    @form(routes.Application.usercheck){
    <form class=frmuuser>
      <input type=text placeholder=email id='emailid'>
      <input type=password placeholder=password id='pwd'>
      <input type=submit value=login id='enter'>

    </form>
    }
```

Comment: You can or you can not add @import at the beginning of the template?

Comment: i put the case class outside the controller..and use  @(form: Form[Userdata]) but its giving me the same error.

Comment: Can you share a sample project that replicates your issue? Also what version of Play Framework are you using?

Comment: @rachitabaderai If your problem was solved, or you found out what the reason was, you may as well update the question details.

Comment: I am having the same problem,  It is driving me bonkers